# How to calculate monosymmetry index of an unequal angle?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, steel

I saw some formula involving integration. Is there a straightforward formula to calculate this instead given b, d, t and alpha angle between x-x and u-u axis?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Give *much* more details. What is "b", "d", "t" and the others?