# How to integrate ∫vᵢ(uᵢ² + vᵢ²)dA in calculating monosymmetry index of an angle?

Tags: civil-engineering, structural-analysis, mathematics, cross-section

I saw this [question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/15228/11443) asking about calculating monosymmetry index of an unequal angle. What I need is a formula to calculate $\int v_i{(u_i}^2 + {v_i}^2)\text{d}A$, given the depth $d$, breadth $b$ and thickness $t$ of an angle. $A$ is the area and $v$ and $u$ are the coordinates of each small element $i$ of the section. Is there a simplified method to derive the above, neglecting root radius and toe radius?

[image: unequal angle]

Comment: Please update your question defining what $v_i$, $u_i$, and $A$ are?

Comment: @unseen_rider, I have updated my question as above.

Comment: Ok I presume $A$ is the Area of the whole cross section?